# Flutter / OneSignal : I'm having trouble using postNotificationWithJson

Tags: android, flutter, dart, onesignal

I am making me an application as a novice developer and I want users to send notifications by location on the device using onesignal postNotificationWithJson (and filters) feature in my application, but I am getting an error and I have been dealing with this error for 2 days but I have not found a solution.

Error :

```
OneSignalRestClient: POST RECEIVED JSON: {"errors":["Please include a case-sensitive header of Authorization: Basic \u003cYOUR-REST-API-KEY-HERE\u003e with a valid REST API key."],"reference":["https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/accounts-and-keys#section-keys-ids"]}
W/OneSignal( 7314): HTTP code: 400 create notification failed
E/flutter ( 7314): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(184)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(OneSignal, Encountered an error attempting to post notification: {"errors":["Please include a case-sensitive header of Authorization: Basic <YOUR-REST-API-KEY-HERE> with a valid REST API key."],"reference":["https:\/\/documentation.onesignal.com\/docs\/accounts-and-keys#section-keys-ids"]}, {reference: [https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/accounts-and-keys#section-keys-ids], errors: [Please include a case-sensitive header of Authorization: Basic <YOUR-REST-API-KEY-HERE> with a valid REST API key.]}, null)
```

Codes (The error goes away when the filters row is deleted.):

```
    var response = await OneSignal.shared.postNotificationWithJson({
  "Authorization":
      "Basic xxxxx",
  "filters": [
    {
      "field": "location",
      "lat": "36.1185207",
      "long": "36.2526271",
      "radius": "800",
    }
  ],

  "headings": {"en": "APP NAME"},
  "contents": {"en": "Click for more information."},
  "data1": {"name": "Markos", "LastName": "Baslik"},
  "data2": {"idName": "KNARNYR"},
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the filter wrong. But I'm getting the Authorization error too

Example:

```
"filters": [
{"field": "tag", "key": "level", "relation": "=", "value": "10"}, 
{"operator": "OR"}, {"field": "amount_spent", "relation": ">", "value": "0"}],
```

Answer (score 0):

I reduced my package to specific version in `pubspec.yaml` file to this one `onesignal_flutter: 3.5.0` AND THE Problem got solve